How to traverse a matrix in a spiral manner such that even if we go outside bounds if we were to come back in the matrix through the pattern we print
You start at the cell (rStart,cStart)  of a  rows×cols grid, facing east. The grid is zero-indexed with the northwest corner at (0,0) and the southeast corner at (rows−1,cols−1). From the starting cell, you will walk in a clockwise spiral, visiting each position in the grid. If you move outside the grid boundary, you continue your walk outside, though you may return to the grid later. Your task is to find the coordinates of all grid cells in the order they are visited, ensuring each cell in the grid is visited exactly once.
Print an array of coordinates representing the positions in the grid in the order they were visited.
Input:
Integer rows: the number of rows in the grid (1 ≤ rows ≤ 100).
Integer cols: the number of columns in the grid (1 ≤ cols ≤ 100).
Integer rStart: the starting row index (0 ≤ rStart < rows).
Integer cStart: the starting column index (0 ≤ cStart < cols).

Output:
A 2D array of coordinates, where each inner array represents a cell visited in order. Each inner array contains two integers [r,c], representing the row and column of the cell, respectively. The outer array holds these coordinates in the exact order they were visited.
Constraints:
1 <= rows, cols <= 100
0 <= rStart < rows
0 <= cStart < cols

Sample Case 1:
Input: 1 4 0 0
Output: [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3]]
Sample Case 2:
Input: 5 6 1 4
Output: [[1,4],[1,5],[2,5],[2,4],[2,3],[1,3],[0,3],[0,4],[0,5],[3,5],[3,4],[3,3],[3,2],[2,2],[1,2],[0,2],[4,5],[4,4],[4,3],[4,2],[4,1],[3,1],[2,1],[1,1],[0,1],[4,0],[3,0],[2,0],[1,0],[0,0]]
This is the logic I tried with (just the logical method I tried):
int main() {

    
    int rStart, cStart, rows, columns;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &rows, &columns, &rStart, &cStart);
    int right = 1, left = -1, up = -1, down = 1;
    int counter = rows*columns ;
    
    printf("%d %d", rStart, cStart);
    rStart --;
    cStart--;
    
    while(counter>0){
    
        int temp1 = cStart;
        cStart = cStart + right;
        
        right = right + 2;
        while(rStart<rows && (rStart>0) && cStart<columns && cStart >0 && temp1<=cStart){
            printf("%d %d", rStart, temp1++);
            counter--;
            if(counter == 0) break;
        }
        int temp2 = rStart;
        rStart = rStart + down;
        
        down = down + 2;
        while(cStart<columns && rStart<columns &&cStart > 0 && rStart >0 && temp2<=rStart){
            printf("%d %d", temp2++, cStart);
            counter--;
            if(counter == 0) break;
        }
        temp1 = cStart;
        cStart = cStart + left;
        left = left - 2;
        while(cStart<columns && rStart<columns &&cStart > 0 && rStart >0 && temp1>=cStart){
            printf("%d %d", rStart, temp1--);
            counter--;
            if(counter == 0) break;
        }
        temp2 = rStart;
        rStart = rStart + up;
        up = up - 2;
        while(cStart<columns && rStart<columns &&cStart > 0 && rStart >0 && temp2>=rStart){
            printf("%d %d", rStart, temp2--);
            counter--;
            if(counter == 0) break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


Make sure you visit How do I ask and answer homework questions? if applicable.

Method: drive an orthoganally moving turtle. If it can't turn right, move straight ahead. But if it is outside the grid, it can turn right. It's unclear though, whether the first step is required to go east.

I have shared my attempt. Here I have just tried using basic while loop to iterate through. Yes the first step is required to go east .

@David C Rankin Thank you so much for this post. Learnt a lot and will try to ask questions better next time

I don't understand why you are adding or subtracting 2 from the direction offsets, and you aren't even using them for anything.

I thought that since we tried spiraling from the certain coordinates, each time we spiraled the length it has to traverse increases by 2. So I added and subtracted 2 above.

Are you allowed to use structures at all?  Have you learned about them yet?

Note that the spiral goes right one, down one, left two, up two, right three, down three, left four, up four, and so on.  All you have to do is keep track of the current position and ensure you record it when it's inside the 5x6 matrix.  You can either count whether you've recorded all the points or you can count whether you've visited all 4 corners of a rectangle or both ends of a 1xN or Nx1 vector or the only entry in a 1x1 'matrix'.  Counting the recorded points is simpler, in fact, but there are alternative algorithms.

the execution of you code takes seconds! What if you have a 1kx1k matrix? Try to decompose the problem: you have a point (couple of integers) that moves on a board. Every time it moves (i.e. change the coordinates), check if it is inside the board and, in this case, print it and decrement the counter of cells. The tricky part is the direction: on the first loop you change it every time, but then you have to keep it more than one step. Write down a sequence (E-S-W-W-N-N....) and try to guess the pattern...do you need a counter? ;-)

#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int rows, columns, rStart, cStart;
scanf("%d %d %d %d", &rows, &columns, &rStart, &cStart);
int cells = 0;
int counter = 1;
int x = rStart, y = cStart;
while(cells < rows*columns){
    for(int i = 0; i<counter; i++){
        //moving right
        if(x>=0 && x<rows && y>=0 && y<columns){
            printf("[%d, %d], ", x, y);
            cells++;
        }
        y++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<counter; i++){
        //moving down
        if(x>=0 && x<rows && y>=0 && y<columns){
            printf("[%d, %d], ", x, y);
            cells++;
        }
        x++;
    }

    counter++;
    for(int i = 0; i<counter; i++){
        //moving left
        if(x>=0 && x<rows && y>=0 && y<columns){
            printf("[%d, %d], ", x, y);
            cells++;
        }
        y--;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<counter; i++){
        //moving right
        if(x>=0 && x<rows && y>=0 && y<columns){
            printf("[%d, %d], ", x, y);
            cells++;
        }
        x--;
    }
    counter++;
}

}enter code here

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
